# Snakemake conda env parameter is not taken from config.yaml file

Tags: bioinformatics, conda, snakemake

I use a conda env that I create manually, not automatically using Snakemake. I do this to keep tighter version control.

Anyway, in my config.yaml I have the following line:

```
conda_env: '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake'
```

Then, at the start of my Snakefile I read that variable (reading variables from config in your shell part does not seem to work, am I right?):

```
conda_env = config['conda_env']
```

Then in  a shell part I hail said parameter like this:

```
rule rsem_quantify:
    input:
        os.path.join(fastq_dir, '{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz'),
        os.path.join(fastq_dir, '{sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz')
    output:
        os.path.join(analyzed_dir, '{sample}.genes.results'),
        os.path.join(analyzed_dir, '{sample}.STAR.genome.bam')
    threads: 8
    shell:
        '''
        #!/bin/bash
        source activate {conda_env}

        rsem-calculate-expression \
        --paired-end \
        {input} \
        {rsem_ref_base} \
        {analyzed_dir}/{wildcards.sample} \
        --strandedness reverse \
        --num-threads {threads} \
        --star \
        --star-gzipped-read-file \
        --star-output-genome-bam
        '''
```

Notice the `{conda_env}`. Now this gives me the following error:

```
Could not find conda environment: None
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

Now, if I change `{conda_env}` for its parameter directly `/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake`, it does work! I don't have any trouble reading other parameters using this method (like `rsem_ref_base` and `analyzed_dir` in the example rule above.

What could be wrong here?

Highest regards,

Freek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern I use is to load variables into `params`, so something along the lines of

```
rule rsem_quantify:
    input:
        os.path.join(fastq_dir, '{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz'),
        os.path.join(fastq_dir, '{sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz')
    output:
        os.path.join(analyzed_dir, '{sample}.genes.results'),
        os.path.join(analyzed_dir, '{sample}.STAR.genome.bam')
    params:
        conda_env=config['conda_env']
    threads: 8
    shell:
        '''
        #!/bin/bash
        source activate {params.conda_env}

        rsem-calculate-expression \

        ...

        '''
```

Although, I'd also never do this with a conda environment, because Snakemake has conda environment management built-in.  See [this section in the docs on Integrated Package Management](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#integrated-package-management) for details. This makes reproducibility much more manageable.

Comment: Thank you, I can use that although it is about as much code as adding the conda env in each shell: part. I was hoping for something global. I understand that I can use conda, perhaps I should but it sounds like such a waist if I can set up my environment once and be done with it. I guess using integrated conda is great for portability though. But I use the same env for all my runs.

Comment: Although with your method I can of course change the env in one place in the config so that is very nice. I will test this when RSEM finishes....

Comment: I thought it worked but it indeed seems to add the conda env nicely however... I get this error now: "/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake/etc/conda/activate.d/java_home.sh: line 1: JAVA_HOME: unbound variable" could this be related? If not ill mark as working and start a new question.

Comment: @Freek that's a conda activation issue. Probably better searching/posting as a separate issue. Though, I will note that it seems you are following the older practice of `source activate...` whereas a more recent best practice was introduced in conda 4.4, which also includes changes to how you manage getting conda on the `PATH`.  See [the v4.4 release notes](https://conda.io/docs/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell) for details.

Comment: Ok, I gave up and started using the build in conda dependencies management (with environment.yaml files) which is pretty great and reproducible as well because I can specify the exact versions of my tools, I found.